# Conditional Logistic Regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, conditional

Firstly, I am new to all of this.

I am currently trying to predict the chance of different students finishing top of their class. Students will be separated into different groups depending on the class they are in (class id), and obviously only one student can finish top of each class (top of class=1, not top of class=0). I have 5 potential variables based on previous scores in past exams, the student's attendance etc

From the basic research I have done, this seems like it would be a conditional logisitic regression, is that correct?

Is it possible to run a conditional logistic regression when there are a different number of students in each class? For example, class 1 has 35 students, class 2 has 18 students, class 3 has 26 students etc.

If so, what would be the best approach for doing this moving forward, what is the best software/package for using conditional logistic regression? I have found lots of support for logistic regression online but not for conditional logistic regression.

Thanks

Comment: How is `top_of_class` determined? Is it that case that every student receives a final score, then you rank them within their class to determine who is top?

Comment: Yes, students are ranked based on their scores. But ultimately, I am just looking for the student that finishes top of the class rather than each specific position within the class rank

Comment: Right, but if you actually know the scores that were used to rank the students, you're throwing away a lot of information by not using them in your model. `top_of_class = 0` could be someone who finished one point behind the leader, or someone right at the bottom of the class.

You'd almost certainly be better off building a model to predict scores, then simulating from it to predict who finishes top of the class.

Comment: That makes sense. In that case, if I am going to create a list/rank of expected scores, would this then become a multinomial/ordinal logistic regression?

Comment: It depends on the data you have. Do you know the actual scores or just the ranks?

Comment: If you only know the ranks, then you would need to fit some sort of ordinal logistic regression model, though you still have the issue of the classes having different sizes.

If you know the scores, even a linear regression model might be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I have access to the scores. My main concern is eventually trying to use this model to predict a students rank if they moved in to a different class, and how I can run this model in the first place with different class sizes

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure I understand the problem. You have some data from past years, which you can use to predict students' final exam score based on various covariates (previous exam scores, attendance, etc.). You now have some new students split into classes of different sizes, where you know exactly which student is in each class, along with their covariate values. You want to predict the probability a student finishes top of their class. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The only difference to your understanding is that there are no new students, but the students are now in different classes compared to last term. I want to predict the probability of each student finishing top of their new class compared to the other students in their class

Comment: In that case it's pretty straightforward. Once you've got your model to predict each student's final score, you can simulate the final table for each class. Does this make sense? I can write out a more detailed answer.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense, thank you. How would I go about creating percentage chance for each student to finish top of the class, where all of the students probabilities sum to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that when there's a continuous outcome followed by ranking, an approach that first predicts the continuous outcome will often be a good idea, because the model gets more information than just a single choice. So, the below is not what I would do in practice, but to theoretically answer the original question, see the below.

However, if one wanted to directly model the "will X get the highest value" as an indicator (1 = highest value, 0 = not), this would still not be a conditional logistic regression. The issue is that the observations in a group are not independent. In your example, one student could be fantastic and predicted to do better than everyone else in their class, but if you add in another similar (or even better) student, then this still reduces their probability of having the highest scores in the class. I.e. this is rather more like a categorical distribution over the students in a class.

A logistic regression with one student as one observation will not capture this correctly, even if you create features like percentile of score, how many students had better previous scores etc. or add a class random effect, because it can still inherently predict that more than 1 student per class gets the best result in the class. Doing this as a conditional logistic regression that conditions on there being just one top result per class does not resolve that. It correctly reflects (and conditions on) that in the training data there happen to only be one top result per class, but when you ask that model to predict there is no immediately obvious way to respect this constraint (which a categorical distribution will respect).

For software to model categorical data, my first thought would be the `categorical` [family of distributions](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/reference/brmsfamily.html) from the `brms` `R` package, but you'd still need to find some tricks to somehow reflect the varying numbers of students per class. Perhaps a 0 offset for students that exist and then for "additional virtual students that don't exist" - i.e. the number up to the maximum class size - a huge negative offset on the logit scale would be a brutal but usable option, you'd probably also want no intercept in a model, because the ID number given to students shouldn't matter and you want all prediction to come from the explanatory covariates.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, you have a dataset of exam scores from previous years. It makes more sense to build a model for predicting a student's final exam score based on various covariates (previous exam scores, attendance, etc.), then use this to predict the probability each student finishes top of their current class.

For simplicity, suppose that you're using a linear regression model for the exam scores. You can estimate the desired probabilities with a simple simulation scheme.

Consider the 35 students from Class 1. If $\hat{y}_i$ is the predicted score for the $i$th student and $\hat{\sigma}_{y_i}$ the associated standard error, you can draw a sample $\tilde{Y}_i^{(1)}\sim\mathcal{N}(\hat{y}_i, \hat{\sigma}_{y_i})$, $i=1,\ldots,35$, from the forecast distribution.

Now repeat the process $N$ times (some large number) and look at how many times each student finishes top of the class.

Comment: There are various things you could do to improve this solution; for example, you can take into account that the $\tilde{Y}_i$ are correlated, as they are based on the same model fit.